# C# async sockets - is async callback always called?

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous, network-programming

If I use:

```
connectionSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, length, SocketFlags.None, out error, new AsyncCallback(SendDataDone), state);
```

Is SendDataDone callback called even in cases when operation was completed synchronously or should I test for asyncRes.CompletedSynchronously and know if it returns true that my callback was not called ?

I would expect that the callback is always called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly, yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/635951/555547.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> Your callback method should invoke the EndSend method. When your
>   application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to
>   execute the specified callback method, and will block on EndSend until
>   the Socket sends the number of bytes requested or throws an exception.

So as long as nothing kills the thread, you've catered for the possible argument exceptions and you're prepared to wait, all should be well.  You probably only need to be aware of handling the possible SocketException or ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense otherwise *EndSend* woul not complete the async call pattern and resources for the request would not be freed..